# When screen rotation ReloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, reloaddata

I can not update my custom view when you turn the screen of my device.

I tried to do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


       var myCustomView = Customview()

       self.view.addsubview(myCustomView)
        }
    }

    override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

        // Reload Data here

        self.view.reloadData() // Incorrect

    }
```

But get me error:

**the method "UIView" does not have a method called reloadData**

Answer (score 3):

You want to call `reloadData()` on the instance of your `UITableView` (assuming there is any). `UIView` does not provide such a method.

**Edit** to get notified when the screen orientation has changed, set up a notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didRotate:", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and implement the selector, e.g.

```
func didRotate(notification: NSNotification)
{
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: how i call reloadData when rotate screen?

Comment: But OP said nothing about tableViews in his question

Comment: That is just an assumption (which I also noted). He asked for `reloadData` and I gave it him.

Comment: I like your approach :) I mean I just was looking at question to find the `tableView` and didn't find !

Comment: @user3351949 you can upvote it then, this is more worth than a comment ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

    // Reload Data here

    self.view.reloadData() // Incorrect

}
```

`UIView` is not a `UITableView` it doesn't have `reloadData` method out of the box.

You can implement this method manually -> have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's work for you

**objective-C**

> [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

**swift**

> self.view.setNeedsDisplay()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    var myCustomView = Customview()
    
    self.view.addsubview(myCustomView)
}

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    
    // Reload Data here
    
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    
}
```

Comment: No this is not working. When I turn my device layout is not regenerated and you see evil